# Javascript - get class owner of a function(method)

Tags: javascript, class, object, methods

there is a way to know what class own a function?
Example:

```
function globalFunc(){
 //alert MyObject
}

function MyObject(){
}
MyObject.prototype.test=function(){
 globalFunc();
}

var o=new MyObject();
o.test();  //alert MyObject
```

Now im using this workaround:

```
function globalFunc(){
 alert(globalFunc.caller.__class__);
}

function MyObject(){
}
MyObject.prototype.test=function(){
 globalFunc();
}
MyObject.prototype.test.__class__=MyObject;

var o=new MyObject();
o.test();  //alert MyObject
```

But there is a big problem, look this:

```
function globalFunc(){
 alert(globalFunc.caller.__class__);
}

function MyObject(){
}
MyObject.prototype.test=function(){
 var temp=function(){
  globalFunc();
 }
 temp(); 
    /* to simulate a simple closure, this may be for example:
     element.addEventListener("click",temp,false);
    */
}
MyObject.prototype.test.__class__=MyObject;

var o=new MyObject();
o.test();  //alert undefined
```

So, there is a clear way to obtain this?
I know where is the problem(**class** property is a property of only test and not temp), but i can't add **class** to temp too.

Thanks.

---

Thanks for reply, some clarification.

Im trying to do a personal framwork OO oriented with private members.

So:

***globalFunc*** is a special function, im using it to get "private" property and i can't call it with call method or passing some arguments, the only arguments im pass is "this":

Example, $() is global

```
Class({
    public:{
        MyClass:function(){
        },

        setName:function(name) {
            $(this).name=name; //set the private var name
        },
        getName:function(){
            return $(this).name;
        }
    },
    private:{
        name:"UNKNOWN"
    }
})

var o=new MyClass();
o.getName(); // UNKNOWN
o.setName("TEST!!!");
o.getName(); // TEST!!!
o.name; //undefined
$(o).name; //undefined
```

To works with inheritance, $(), i need to know what class call it and the object of the class.

All works good, but if i need to access a private members in a clousure i must add 
**__class__**
 property to clouser!! And i not want this!

Thanks again and sorry for my bad english, im not native speaker.

Comment: You'll have to unlearn the idea that there is such a thing as a "class" in JavaScript. There ain't.

Answer (score 3):

In javascript there are no Classes. Instead several objects can "own" the same function. For example:

```
function myFun(){
  alert(this.name);
}

function Obj1(){
  this.name = "obj1";
}
Obj1.prototype.fun = myFun;

function Obj2(){
  this.name = "obj2";
}
Obj2.prototype.fun = myFun;
var obj1 = new Obj1();
var obj2 = new Obj2();
obj1.fun();
obj2.fun();
```

Comment: @CoDEmanX ES6 classes are just syntax sugar. Defining a method in a class is the same as setting the method on the prototype of the constructor

Answer (score 2):

You scenario is not entirely clear but here are some options:-

```
 function globalFunc()
 {
     alert(this.__class__);
     //Note globalFunc now has access to much more.
 }

 function MyObject(){ }
 MyObject.prototype.test=function(){
   globalFunc.call(this);
 }
 MyObject.prototype.__class__=MyObject;
```

To add a closure for event handling

```
MyObject.prototype.test = function(){
   var self = this;
   var elem = //get some element;
   //Not cross-browser but for illustration
   elem.addEventListener('click', fnEvent);
   function fnEvent() { globalFunc.call(self); }
   elem = null
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand well what you are trying to do, but here's an idea that could inspire you something.
The "constructor" property helped me well when I was trying to use JS as a OO language.

`o.constructor` will give you the `myObject` function reference.

But in my opinion, you should give functional programming a try instead of OO to get the most from Javascript

Answer (score 0):

`temp` is the caller but it does not have the property `__class__`. You only defined that for `test`.

Comment: Yes..indeed im asking here if someone know another solution.

Comment: ps. i cant add __class__ property to temp too.

Answer (score 0):

`caller` is non-standardised and really brittle; best avoided. Much better to pass the value explicitly:

```
MyObject.prototype.test= function() {
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
        globalFunc(MyObject);
    });
};
```

or:

```
MyObject.prototype.test= function() {
    var myclass= arguments.callee.__class__;
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
        globalFunc(myclass);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions are not "owned" in JavaScript. Functions are first class objects in JavaScript, which means they can be passed around like any other variable and assigned as properties of many objects.

`this` inside a function body will give you a reference to the object on which the function was called, if called as a method (e.g. `myObj.myMethod()`) or via the Function prototype's `call()` or `apply()` methods (e.g. `myFunc.call(myObj)`). Inside a function called on its own (e.g. `myFunc()`), `this` will usually be the global object (the same as `window` in most browsers).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, there really is no way to do what you are trying to do. Javascript just doesn't work like that.

Long answer...

Almost every programmer I've met who has come to JavaScript from a language that uses a classical object model has tried to do what you are doing: emulate the classical OOP style they are used to with Javascript.
There is no shame here, I did this, even the famous Douglas Crockford experimented with this, and then later gave it up. I did too. I still think it was a neccessary thing for me to try this stuff in order to really learn the langauage

Do not be fooled by the curly braces, and familiar looking operators. At it's core it has very little in common with Java! JavaScript is a functional langauge: functions are objects in their own right.

Bluntly: There is no way to do what you are trying to do - have objects with private properties you can access through *this*

Saying that is easy :) Understanding how to apply that is more difficult

There are no classes, there are only objects.
Objects only have properties.
Properties of objects may have values.
Those values may be functions.
*this* is set when the function gets called, it could be anything

Closure is the only way to achieve true privacy in JavaScript. Everything else either leaks into some enclosing scope, relies on obfuscated property names, or can be circumvented in some way by the caller, or leaks memory even after your objects are no longer referenced (as there are no destructor function to do your clean-up in).

What you are doing is still a good thing to try and do, by attempting it you will become a better JavaScript programmer by figuring out:
 why you can't do some of it
 more importantly why you probably shouldn't